# How can one close HTML tags in Vim quickly?

Tags: html, xml, vim, autocomplete

It's been a while since I've had to do any HTML-like code in `Vim`, but recently I came across this again. Say I'm writing some simple `HTML`:

```
<html><head><title>This is a title</title></head></html>
```

How do I write those closing tags for title, head and html down quickly? I feel like I'm missing some really simple way here that does not involve me going through writing them all down one by one.

Of course I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to autocomplete the individual tag names but what gets me on my laptop keyboard is actually getting the brackets and slash right.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check this out..

closetag.vim

```
Functions and mappings to close open HTML/XML tags
```

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=13

I use something similar.

Comment: I have installed this. It doesn't completed close tag automatically.What is the shortkey? I try `Ctrl-_`, but this make small font of my terminal.

Answer (score 78):

I find using the [xmledit](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301) plugin pretty useful.  it adds two pieces of functionality:

1. When you open a tag (*e.g.* type `<p>`), it expands the tag as soon as you type the closing `>` into `<p></p>` and places the cursor inside the tag in insert mode.
2. If you then immediately type another `>` (*e.g.* you type `<p>>`), it expands that into

   `<p>`

   `</p>`

and places the cursor inside the tag, indented once, in insert mode.

The [xml](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1397) vim plugin adds code folding and nested tag matching to these features.

Of course, you don't have to worry about closing tags at all if you write your HTML content in [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and use `%!` to filter your Vim buffer through the Markdown processor of your choice :)

Comment: Can this plugin auto-close tags when '</' is typed? Or just insert closing tag with some keystroke? Sometimes you delete the closing tag and want it inserted afterwards...

Comment: I uninstalled it because it made my gvim blinking on starting

Comment: I don't like this plugin because it doesn't provide an easy way to get your cursor past of the generated tag.  For example, if you want to write "Have a <b>nice</b> day", you start off by typing "Have a <b>nice", which renders as "Have a <b>nice|</b>".  You then need to either right-arrow across or exit insert mode to continue with the rest of the sentence.

That's why a solution where you press a key to insert the end tag is better.

Comment: @exclipy Vim has plenty of built-in ways to do this. Try the the 'E', 'f', and 'A' commands for starters.

Comment: I installed xmledit plugin with `git clone https://github.com/sukima/xmledit.git ~/.vim/bundle/xmledit`. But it only works when editing .xml files. When the file ext is .html or .htm, it doesn't works.

Comment: @Chad currently, the my solution was to copy paste the file in the same directory exact rename it to "html.vim" so that it will effect HTML files as well. Now, I have two of the exact same files in ~/.vim/ftplugin (xml.vim and html.vim).

Comment: @SilentDev the README also recommends symlinking. But overwriting plugin files is ridiculously user-unfriendly.

Answer (score 60):

I like minimal things,

```
imap ,/ </<C-X><C-O>
```

Comment: What does <C-X><C-O> do?  It doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: There are cases where one would like to write ",/", so I'd rather user a different shortcut. Another detail is that the omni-completion should be closed, not waiting for additional input. So: `imap <silent> <C-c> </<C-X><C-O><C-X>`

Comment: Very cool. Also added `<Esc>F<i` to the end of this so it puts the cursor back inside the tag.

Comment: to use this command be in insert mode, then hit `,/` to close the tag

Comment: The above solution has a lot of upvotes but it lacks explanation especially for a beginner like me. How does it work and how does one use it?

Comment: Logging in after 10 years to get this myself as at some point it fell out of my vimrc, it uses omni comption (https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Omni_completion) to close the current tag in html mode files, I think i mapped it to "./" because it was quick to type and normally followed by opening a new line but i'll put it somewhere else now

Comment: Remember to put `<buffer>` on the mapping so that it's not used for non-xml files.

Comment: @PhemeloKhetho (also for future visitors) Type `:help imap` and `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-O` (or simply `:help ^x^o`)). For "what does it do" see  [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130734/how-can-one-close-html-tags-in-vim-quickly#comment78038565_532656) _____________________________________________________________________________________________ **Warning**: this may **do nothing** (insert only `</>`) if the HTML is ill-formed, for example, with unmatched tags. (even if the browser might handle the error fine)

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Auto_closing_an_HTML_tag reference

Answer (score 53):

I find it more convinient to make vim write both opening and closing tag for me, instead of just the closing one. You can use excellent [ragtag plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896) by Tim Pope. Usage looks like this (let | mark cursor position)
you type:

```
span|
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

and you get

```
<span>|</span>
```

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, and you get

```
<span>
|
</span>
```

Ragtag can do more than just it (eg. insert <%= stuff around this %> or DOCTYPE). You probably want to check out other plugins by [author of ragtag](http://www.vim.org/account/profile.php?user_id=9012), especially [surround](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697).

Comment: +1 Awesome! Btw, this is now known as `ragtag`: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896

Comment: This one is definitely the simplest. Textmate had it good, but Vim beats it with this, thanks Krzysiek.

Answer (score 24):

If you're doing anything elaborate, [sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) is very good.

An example from their site:

`ul > li.item-$*3` expands to:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item-1"></li>
    <li class="item-2"></li>
    <li class="item-3"></li>
</ul>
```

with a `<C-e>`.

To do the example given in the question,

```
html > head > title{This is a title}
```

yields

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!  This is cooler than anything I've seen before, not only Vim but among any other editors!  Super!

Comment: This is a great plugin

Comment: This plugin evolved from zen-coding. The latter is now known as [emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim) and has a slightly larger feature set.

Answer (score 19):

There is also a zencoding vim plugin: https://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim

tutorial: https://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim/blob/master/TUTORIAL

---

**Update:** this now called ***Emmet***: http://emmet.io/

---

An excerpt from the tutorial:

```
1. Expand Abbreviation

  Type abbreviation as 'div>p#foo$*3>a' and type '<c-y>,'.
  ---------------------
  <div>
      <p id="foo1">
          <a href=""></a>
      </p>
      <p id="foo2">
          <a href=""></a>
      </p>
      <p id="foo3">
          <a href=""></a>
      </p>
  </div>
  ---------------------

2. Wrap with Abbreviation

  Write as below.
  ---------------------
  test1
  test2
  test3
  ---------------------
  Then do visual select(line wize) and type '<c-y>,'.
  If you request 'Tag:', then type 'ul>li*'.
  ---------------------
  <ul>
      <li>test1</li>
      <li>test2</li>
      <li>test3</li>
  </ul>
  ---------------------

...

12. Make anchor from URL

  Move cursor to URL
  ---------------------
  http://www.google.com/
  ---------------------
  Type '<c-y>a'
  ---------------------
  <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
  ---------------------
```

Comment: whoa, is that by the creator of ruby?

Answer (score 17):

### Mapping

I like to have my block tags (as opposed to inline) closed immediately and with as simple a shortcut as possible (I like to avoid special keys like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> where possible, though I do use `closetag.vim` to close my inline tags.) I like to use this shortcut when starting blocks of tags (thanks to @kimilhee; this is a take-off of his answer):

```
inoremap ><Tab> ><Esc>F<lyt>o</<C-r>"><Esc>O<Space>
```

### Sample usage

Type—

```
<p>[Tab]
```

Result—

```
<p>
 |
</p>
```

where `|` indicates cursor position.

### Explanation

- `inoremap` *means* create the mapping in insert mode
- `><Tab>` *means* a closing angle brackets and a tab character; this is what is matched
- `><Esc>` *means* end the first tag and escape from insert into normal mode
- `F<` *means* find the last opening angle bracket
- `l` *means* move the cursor right one (don't copy the opening angle bracket)
- `yt>` *means* yank from cursor position to up until before the next closing angle bracket (i.e. copy tags contents)
- `o</` *means* start new line in insert mode and add an opening angle bracket and slash
- `<C-r>"` *means* paste in insert mode from the default register (`"`)
- `><Esc>` *means* close the closing tag and escape from insert mode
- `O<Space>` *means* start a new line in insert mode above the cursor and insert a space

Comment: @wds Wow, yeah, I never thought about the fact that `l` meant "right" and not "left," haha... what a funny error. What did you think of my post? I noticed you didn't upvote.

Comment: Nice for sure. I've taken to using the xml.vim plugin recently (it does work quite nicely). I would suggest adding it to your .vimrc with a filetype-specific autocommand, i.e.: `au filetype html inoremap <buffer> ...`

Comment: Finally an Autoclose command that works exactly as it should --simply!

Comment: I like to keep my cursor in between tags. So I modified it to suit my need. `inoremap ><Tab> ><Esc>F<lyt>o</<C-r>"><Esc>kJxi` I remove `0<Space>` and added `kJxi`. 
Go 1 step up, concatenate two lines, remove one character then go into insert mode.

Answer (score 12):

## Check out [`vim-closetag`](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag)

It's a really simple script (also available as a `vundle` plugin) that closes (X)HTML tags for you. From it's `README`:

> If this is the current content:
>
> ```
> <table|
> ```
>
> Now you press <kbd>></kbd>, the content will be:
>
> ```
> <table>|</table>
> ```
>
> And now if you press <kbd>></kbd> again, the content will be:
>
> ```
> <table>
>    |
> </table>
> ```

---

*Note: `|` is the cursor here*

Answer (score 7):

Here is yet another simple solution based on easily foundable Web writing:

1. [Auto closing an HTML tag](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_closing_an_HTML_tag)

   `:iabbrev </ </<C-X><C-O>`
2. [Turning completion on](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19021#Vim-7-Turning-completion-on)

   `autocmd FileType xml set omnifunc=xmlcomplete#CompleteTags`

Comment: Awesome response!!! with no plugin!!! (2nd item has linkrot) still perhaps best answer of all, because it seems quicker to modify the .vimrc rather than handling plugins. Plus most minimalist response

Comment: This adds space after closed tag :(

Answer (score 6):

allml (now Ragtag ) and Omni-completion ( <C-X><C-O> )
doesn't work in a file like .py or .java.

if you want to close tag automatically in those file,
you can map like this.

```
imap <C-j> <ESC>F<lyt>$a</^R">
```

( ^R is Contrl+R : you can type like this Control+v and then Control+r )

(| is cursor position )
now if you type..

<p>abcde|

and type ^j

then it close the tag like this..

<p>abcde</p>|

Comment: with imap <C-j> <ESC>mfF<lyt>`fa</<C-R>"> the clonsing tag is where the cursor was when you typed ^j instead of the end of line ($)

Answer (score 5):

Building off of the excellent answer by @KeithPinson (sorry, not enough reputation points to comment on your answer yet), this alternative will prevent the autocomplete from copying anything extra that might be inside the html tag (e.g. classes, ids, etc...) but should not be copied to the closing tag.

**UPDATE** I have updated my response to work with `filename.html.erb` files.
I noticed my original response didn't work in files commonly used in Rails views, like `some_file.html.erb` when I was using embedded ruby (e.g. `<p>Year: <%= @year %><p>`).  The code below *will* work with `.html.erb` files.

```
inoremap ><Tab> ><Esc>?<[a-z]<CR>lyiwo</<C-r>"><Esc>O
```

**Sample usage**

Type:

```
<div class="foo">[Tab]
```

Result:

```
<div class="foo">
  |
<div>
```

where `|` indicates cursor position

And as an example of adding the closing tag inline instead of block style:

```
inoremap ><Tab> ><Esc>?<[a-z]<CR>lyiwh/[^%]><CR>la</<C-r>"><Esc>F<i
```

**Sample usage**

Type:

```
<div class="foo">[Tab]
```

Result:

```
<div class="foo">|<div>
```

where `|` indicates cursor position

It's true that both of the above examples rely on `>[Tab]` to signal a closing tag (meaning you would have to choose **either** inline or block style).  Personally, I use the block-style with `>[Tab]` and the inline-style with `>>`.