# Tag completion with vim?

Tags: vim, textmate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one close html tags in vim quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130734/how-can-one-close-html-tags-in-vim-quickly)

One of my favorite features of TextMate is the ability to type out a tag, say `<div>`, and press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, it will automatically insert the corresponding end tag, `</div>`.

How can I do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [`xmledit`](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301) plugin for this.

> ...When in insert mode and you finish a tag (pressing '>') the 
>   tag will be completed. If you press '>' twice it will complete the tag and 
>   place the cursor in the middle of the tags on it's own line.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used TextMate so I'm not sure if this is quite the same thing but there is a vim plugin called snipmate that may help you out.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Comment: use Sparkup div +Ctrl-e http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2010/03/04/write-html-faster-with-sparkup-vim-and-textmate/