# Use closetag.vim script in .html.eb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/130741/168646 I learned about closetag.vim, which is exactly what I was hoping to find.  However, I can't seem to get it working for the `.html.erb` files in my rails project.

I tried adding `erb` and `html.erb` to the list of file types that source the script (in my .vimrc file):

`autocmd Filetype html,xml,erb,html.erb source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file type of .erb files is `eruby`.  Add it to your `autocmd`:

```
autocmd Filetype html,xml,eruby source ~/.vim/scripts/closetag.vim
```

To determine what filetype Vim is using for a file, you can do:

```
set filetype?
" Shows:
" filetype=eruby
```