# How can I use vim autocomplete for EJS files

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ejs

I recently started learning vim and I wanted to create a node app using it. Is there a way that I can autocomplete HTML tags for .ejs files?

It would be helpful if I can start typing the tag and then use autocomplete to place both the opening and closing tags leaving the cursor in the middle like plugins in other IDEs.

Comment: I hope this will work https://stackoverflow.com/a/130741/8379852

Comment: I was hoping there would be a faster way such as those in IDEs where I can just start typing the tag and when I autocomplete it would put both the opening and closing tags and place my cursor in the middle

Comment: Then you should go for `VSCode` because vim is a very basic editor.

Comment: Yeah I think I will use vim key binds with vscode after I get comfortable with it